# How do I seal the connection between my male threaded faucet and a female brass adapter?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, fitting, adapter, seal

I’m pretty new to this, so I may be down a wrong path. Ultimately I’m trying to connect a garden hose connection to my bathroom faucet, but my faucet is too small. After a lot of measuring and trial and error, I found an adapter/fitting that fits my faucet:

[image: Side picture of 1/2” to garden hose adapter]

[image: Front picture of 1/2” to garden hose adapter]

I’ll try to keep it short and sweet:

- **Faucet**: male threads (*I think 1/2”*)
- **Hose**: female garden hose threads
- **Adapter**: 1/2” female to garden hose male
- **Hose to Adapter**: includes rubber gasket, no leak
- **Faucet to Adapter**: no gasket included, leaks a lot
- **Threads**: I think all the threads involved are straight, not tapered (*I’m not 100% sure though*)

If all the threads are straight like I think they are, then I know I need a gasket on the faucet side of the adapter. I just don’t know where to install one since there’s no internal rim or anything.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: That adapter has internal threads that are *pipe thread* which, incidentally, is a tapered thread. I have never seen a bathroom faucet that had a spout with pipe thread. I think you have the wrong fitting and need to look at adapter fittings for *faucet spout threads*, which are usually found in the plumbing shop alongside the *faucet aerators*. There are many *possible* sizes but there are a few that are the most common.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the PTFE tape - usually in white to do this.

Easily available in any hardware or DIY / hombase type store.

Just remember to wrap the tape around the threads in the clockwise direction (otherwise the action of tightening the threads cause the tape to unwrap and bunch up).

You could also use a thread jointing compound - I have one that is fantastic and stays "soft" while still sealing. It is designed for many applications other than water though. Sticks to fingers well :)